# multiple solr version on a server

Tags: apache, solr

I have solr4.8.1 on the server. This will continue to operate until further notice. Now I need solr6.6.3 on the same server. Is it possible to install the solr6.6.3 without further conflicts without coming into conflict with the solr4.8.1? It only needs to be respected on the port, right?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have a different home directories (so that the index directories doesn't clash), and both Solr versions support the JVM you're running (and if not - you'll have to have multiple JVMs installed and set the appropriate environment variables for that), having multiple versions installed will work just fine.

But if you decide to use the same data directory (and home/config), you'll bork either version - the index files will be upgraded, and the 4.x version will no longer be able to read them - and the config might not work on 6 by itself, since the default types has changed.

Comment: OK, thank you.

solr6.6.3 stores the data in the folder / opt / ... that does not solr4.8.1. Should therefore fit?

Comment: As long as the directories (and if you're using cloud, the zookeeper nodes) are kept separate, it should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I find the Solr documentation on how to install Solr for production much better for this: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_5/taking-solr-to-production.html#taking-solr-to-production

You can easily install multiple versions in different directories and under different service names by supplying the relevant arguments to the install script:

E.g. `solr-8.5.2/bin/install_solr_service.sh solr-8.5.2.tgz -d /var/solr8 -p 8984 -s solr8`